# How to trigger a Azure DevOps pipeline when a new PR is created?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

All I found was something like this, "when a branch is updated the pipeline is triggered". But what I need is when a new pull request from a branch is created, the pipeline runs!

I´m trying to do this but happens what I said before, the pipeline is triggered when a new update is made in the branch and not when a PR is created...

[image]

I just need a way to trigger my Azure DevOps pipeline when a new PR is created.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

The `pr` trigger in the Azure DevOps schema is specific to using git repositories that are hosted in GitHub.

If you're using git in Azure DevOps, PR triggers are not defined in the YAML. Instead, you need to:

1. Setup a branch policy on the branch that you want to protect.  (Pipelines -> Branches, then select *Branch policies* in the ellipsis.)

   [image: Branch Policy]
2. Add your pipeline to the Build Validation section of the branch policy.

   [image: Build Validation]
3. Then configure pipeline with the paths and whether it should be triggered manually as part of the PR or automatically with each push.

   [image]